# RemoteAudioTrack's native MediaStreamTrack is 'ended' on mute and not going back to 'live' state

Tags: agora.io

Here is the [demo](https://github.com/AgoraIO/API-Examples-Web/blob/main/Demo/basicMute/basicMute.js) with mute unmute logic of agora client lib

Main problem is that MediaStreamTrack switching to 'ended' state after **setMuted** or **setEnabled** and it is not going back to 'live' state after reverse action on those methods of **LocalAudioTrack** so I can't use it with AudioContext for audio processing.

Even [volume-indicator](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/web_ng/interfaces/iagorartcclient.html#event_volume_indicator) event on AgoraClient stops firing after mute and unmute actions on LocalAudioTrack

So what is proper way to make mute and unmute and to get actual active native **MediaStreamTrack**?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `setMuted` method which doesn't destroy the track (only stops publishing it) for your use case to continue your processing on the track.

I'm unable to reproduce the the `volume-indicator` event stopping after mute as you described, I'm attaching a screenshot of the log below.

[image: console log]